# Forced to import R.Java

Tags: android, android-studio

EDIT: Problem typically seems to lie with Files that reside within folders. In the image below, you'll notice how the MainActivity does not have any issues, despite having multiple references to the R.Java file. The java files within the Fragments folder that refer to the R.Java return errors. Infact, if you move an offending file out from within the Fragments folder, the problem is instantly resolved.

[image]

Currently merging branches of a project, and Android Studio is constantly claiming I need to add import statements for R.Java.
Previously this was not something I needed to do, and I'm guessing somewhere in the merge the R.Java file was tweaked or moved and now it's forcing me to manually find it each time.
Any ideas as to the cause, and any recommendations other than just importing R.Java as necessary?

Comment: clean your project and re-build

Comment: @USKMobility Already tried cleaning, can't rebuild because the absence of R.Java causes the build to fail.

Answer (score 1):

R.java is a generated file and is always created **inside the package name of your app**. Whatever your package name is in your manifest - that's where R.java is created.

If you want to access it's fields (i.e resource IDs) from other packages, you need to import the class, just like you would with any another class.